# How to upgrade a mac from 10.4?

Tags: upgrade, macos

An old MacBook still running 10.4 just showed up. Unfortunately, 10.4 isn't new enough to run the software it needs to run, so I'm trying to figure out how to upgrade it something newer.

The usual answers seem to be to buy a Snow Leopard box set and work from there, but Apple doesn't sell those anymore, at least not as far as I can tell. From what I can find, they actually don't sell any physical upgrade media, which is a bit of a problem, since this mac obviously doesn't have the App Store.

What's the best way to deal with this?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a 12" Powerbook G4 running 10.4 and it runs fine. I've just upgraded its memory to the maximum 1.25 Gb. I think that won't be enough to run Leopard well. Note that you cannot run Snow Leopard in a PPC machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in the US or Canada, you can call 1-800-MY-APPLE to order Snow Leopard directly from Apple telesales. It should only be $20, a discount from the original $30 price.

This will only work if you have an Intel Mac, of course.